# MacBook Pro, Storage Space Gone After Merging All Partitions

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, macos-catalina

I merged all my partitions into the one I have MacOS on using `diskutil` and the storage space are gone.

Before:

[image]

After:
[image]
[image]
Edit:
`diskutil list`

command output

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         124.6 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +124.6 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume userdata - Data         110.4 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 90.9 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.5 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.7 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume userdata                10.7 GB    disk1s5
```

Comment: On your second screenshot, can you try to increase the Size from `125GB` to `251GB`? I assume there's an apply button somewhere outside of the crop. It looks like you've just removed the partitions, but left the space unallocated.

Comment: DO NOT do any more partition work without more discussion. Do not write anything to the volume.

Comment: If you have a Time Machine backup, you can do [Restore](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203981).

Comment: @harrymc I don't want any my data. I just want the storage space back!

Comment: If you would like to consolidate the space, delete all partitions and create one over the entire volume - [link](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/partition-a-physical-disk-dskutl14027/mac). Is that it?

Comment: Or just format the disk and create one partition.

Comment: @MichaelFrank I can't modify anything on the partition panel. When I try to resize it, after I type the number in and press enter, the number goes back to 125GB.

Comment: I am looking for an answer that doesn't need to erase the partition my macos is currently on.

Comment: Add the result of the terminal command `diskutil list` to your question.

Comment: Added! Please help me solve this problem. This have been bothering me since last year. Now I've got around 1MB left and struggling to use because it often got 100% full and I have to erase some of my file.

Comment: There's output missing from your diskutil command. Where's /dev/disk0? What you have here is the artificial APFS disk (container) /dev/disk1, which is contained in /dev/disk0. In order to help we'll need the full output.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't put all the outputs.

Comment: shaded area means occupied space and since all your partitions where shaded then how can you expect free space after merging them and please update your question regarding what you want !!!

Comment: @Madhubala my hard drive is 251GB as shown in the screenshot. Although it is my only partition, it only has 125GB. There's 126GB gone MISSING!!

Comment: i hope you won't mind attaching a screenshot without that resize window and with Show All Devices options chosen

Comment: Do you mean the "Before" screenshot? I'm sorry, I didn't take the full window. I can't get back to that stage(I wish I could).

Comment: i mean - just click cancel in second screenshot you attached and choose Show All Devices option > select your Apple SSD and then take the screenshot